# Get JSON value from key value array with Angular

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

Hi I am new to angular and just trying to learn how to do a few things. I have got stuck in trying to display the following data. Using the Batarang plugin for chrome i can see my restful webservice returning the following json which is wrapped into my model.

```
    { 
    course:  { 
        country: Test1
        numberEnrolledPerMonthPerWeek:  { 
            entry: 
            [  { 
                key: 2
                value:  { 
                    numberEnrolled: 0
                    weeks: 2
                    year: 2011
                } 
            } ,  { 
                key: 3
                value:  { 
                    numberEnrolled: 4
                    weeks: 3
                    year: 2011
                } 
            } ,  { 
                key: 4
                value:  { 
                    numberEnrolled: 6
                    weeks: 4
                    year: 2011
                } 
            } ,  { 
                key: 8
                value:  { 
                    numberEnrolled: 0
                    weeks: 8
                    year: 2011
                } 
            }  
            ]
        } 
    } 
 }
```

I am trying to get the numberEnrolled value out for each key into a column. So in my html I have the following

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
            <tr ng-repeat="course in enrolledcourses.enrolledEnrolment">
                <td>                                
                    {{course.country}}
                </td>   
                <td>
                    {{course.numberEnrolledPerMonthPerWeek[2].numberEnrolled}}
                </td>               
            </tr>   
        </table>
```

{{course.numberEnrolledPerMonthPerWeek[2].numberEnrolled}} does not return me any value so can anyone advise what would be the correct syntax to get the numberEnrolled value please.

I have tried

```
{{course.numberEnrolledPerMonthPerWeek.2.numberEnrolled}}
{{course.numberEnrolledPerMonthPerWeek[2][numberEnrolled]}}
```

My controller code is as follows

```
.controller('PeopleCtrl', function($scope, recruitmentFactory) {
    $scope.enrolledcourses = recruitmentFactory.get();


    $scope.test = "hello";
    $scope.save = function() {
        alert("save has been called");
    };
})
```

Comment: if this is in a controller, please show it. is the model in the `$scope`? in any case, numberEnrolledPerMonthPerWeek is an object and the field `2` doesn't exist there

Comment: i can see that it is an object but how do i get to the entries in that object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, your JSON has plenty of mistakes. maybe it's just the output you got, but just in case::
there are missing commas and Test is a symbol but I guess it's intenteded to be a string.

```
$scope.enrolledcourses = {
    course : {
    country: 'Test1',
    numberEnrolledPerMonthPerWeek: {
        entry: [{
            key: 2,
            value: {
                numberEnrolled: 0,
                weeks: 2,
                year: 2011,
            }
        }, {
            key: 3,
            value: {
                numberEnrolled: 4,
                weeks: 3,
                year: 2011
            }
        }, {
            key: 4,
            value: {
                numberEnrolled: 6,
                weeks: 4,
                year: 2011
            }
        }, {
            key: 8,
            value: {
                numberEnrolled: 0,
                weeks: 8,
                year: 2011
            }
        }]
    }
    }
};
```

then your html needs to access the correct properties:

```
    <tr ng-repeat="course in enrolledcourses">
        <td>{{course.country}}</td>
        <td>{{course.numberEnrolledPerMonthPerWeek.entry[2].value.numberEnrolled}}</td>
    </tr>
```

this is a [live example](http://jsfiddle.net/egamonal/FThXw/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Just to provide some extra help: I run into this problem a lot with figuring out how to navigate through JSON data. Try using visualization tools, and validate your JSON to make sure its correct.

Here is what I use to visualize the data:
http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/
Validation here:
http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
numberEnrolledPerMonthPerWeek[2] is not your array
```

try

```
numberEnrolledPerMonthPerWeek.entry[2]
```

Comment: trying the above produces {"key":"4","value":{"numberEnrolled":"6","weeks":"4","year":"2011"}}

Answer (score 0):

Okay so i did the following to get the value out

```
{{course.numberEnrolledPerMonthPerWeek.entry[2].value.numberEnrolled}}
```